# Getting null value from 'document.getElementById()'

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have following confirmation box on `review.xhtml` page:

```
<p:confirmDialog message="#{msgs['com.yob.dpg.customerReview.invalid.invoiceDate.message']}" width="400" header="#{msgs['portaal.popup.window.confirmation.title']}" closable="false" widgetVar="invoiceDateConfirmation" showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" severity="alert">
            <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['portaal.popup.window.cancel']}" onclick="invoiceDateConfirmation.hide()" oncomplete="documentWiz.back(); setFocusToInvoiceNumber()" /> 
            <p:spacer width="5"/>  
            <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['common.ok.button']}" update="messages,@form,headerForm:todoCountMenu,welcomeMessage" onclick="invoiceDateConfirmation.hide()" />  
</p:confirmDialog>
```

and `.js` is on `documentPreview.xhtml` page:

```
function setFocusToInvoiceNumber(){
    document.getElementById("invoiceNumber").focus();
}
```

input text code on which I want to set focus is on 'documentPreview.xhtml':

```
<p:inputText  style="color:#4d4d4f; width:280px !important; margin-top: -3px;" id="invoiceNumber" value="#{customerReviewLazyDataModel.customerReviewVO.transactionheaderVO.invoiceNumber}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msgs['com.yob.dpg.customerReview.mandatory.invoiceNumber']}"/>
```

My problem is that when I click on cancel button of confirmation box, an exception is thrown on browser that 'document.getElementById() is null'

Can any one give me solution for this problem.

Comment: The js code is executing first so put the js code below your html.

Answer (score 0):

Because the component id in JSF is not the same as the HTML DOM object ID, you can see this when you check the component id in the generated HTML file.

Check this blog post ([JSF: working with component identifiers (id/clientId)](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html)) by [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell)

Answer (score 0):

try adding prependId=false attribute to your form. this will keep the ids of all its children when JSF will generate the html.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the rendered html in your browser. The id of the input element is probably something like "form1:invoiceNumber" instead of simply invoiceNumber. This is because JSF prepends all the parent NamingContainer id's to a component upon rendering to html.

In order to resolve this, you could turn off the prepend id feature like @sergui suggested, but that could have some adverse effect (namely, duplicate id's if composite components are reused multiple times on the same page). Another option is to store the "clientId" (the part that JSF prepends) in javascript.

To do so, add init(String clientId) function to the js file, then call it using an inline script from the JSF facelet

```
<h:outputScript>init('#{component.clientId}')</h:outputScript>
```

You'd then have to prepend invoiceNumber with clientId, but only after escaping the delimiter that JSF uses (:).